# Which statistic test for difference in downloads per week?

Tags: probability, statistics, poisson-distribution

Let's say I have the following dataset of downloads per day grouped per week.

```
week1: 1 0 0 0 1 0 0
week2: 2 0 2 0 0 2 0
```

Now I want to know whether the downloads in week1 are significantly different compared to week2. Which statistical test do I apply? Poisson, randomization-test or something else?

I tried a randomization test of 10k iterations. The p-value is about: 0.17. The t-test is 0.2326. Now I think somehow Poisson should model it better, but I don't know how to do it.

Comment: You need much more data if you want any kind of significant result. Also, you might want to check out [stats.SE], our sister site about statistics.

Comment: I want to compare weeks, so this is the data there is. There will never be more data than this. The only thing what could happen is there's just more downloads per week. So I just want to know which test I should apply, which could also be used for other weeks.

Comment: @Ansjovis86, I agree with what AlexR has said- you have two groups of 7 which is very small. I understand that weeks have 7 days and that is immutable, so can you wait a few more weeks and get more weeks or "rows" in your dataset? This could help the small sample problem somewhat.

Comment: @Ansjovis86 You would have many more weeks. The problem is that your current sample size is 2. All you could say here is that week1 happens to only have a third of the downloads if week2, but no explanation for it. You first need assumptions (such as the number of downloads is uniformly distributed among the days of week, but per week there's pattern XYZ) Then you can test this specific hypothesis. The problem at hand is that it's very hard to generate meaningful hypotheses from such a small sample.

Comment: @ScouserInTrousers But the goal is to compare weeks. Which test should I take. I know this comparison is probably not significant, but in a new week it might be significant.